# Rails 4 devise user is able to sign up but not signin in ,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building an rails app (I'm using rails 4) and using Devise for authentication, the problem is that I'm able to sign up and after sign up the user is automatically signed in , but if I log out , I'm not able to sign in anymore, here are my codes for the model controller and routes.

controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password,   :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :password) }
  end
end
```

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username)
  end
end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

  resources :rezultates

  resources :notificaris do
    member do
      get :trimite
      get :trimiteneplata
      get :tz
    end
  end

  resources :programaris

  resources :pacients do
    collection { post :import }
    resources :programaris
    resources :rezultates
    member do
      get :trimite
    end
  end

  root to: 'pacients#index'
end
```

the log from the server when i'm tryng to sign in

```
   Started GET "/users/login" for 81.180.92.184 at 2014-06-30 09:41:33 +0300
   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.8ms)
   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (16.8ms)
   Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 60.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


   Started POST "/users/login" for 81.180.92.184 at 2014-06-30 09:41:42 +0300
   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"y47xQa7rSBkLS1Yp1PjqKTX1tRmzQ/VN+U6GJenETR8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"ionut@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Autentificare"}
   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms
   Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"y47xQa7rSBkLS1Yp1PjqKTX1tRmzQ/VN+U6GJenETR8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"ionut@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Autentificare"}
   Unpermitted parameters: email
   Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.8ms)
   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (15.0ms)
   Completed 200 OK in 235ms (Views: 66.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: can you post your logs when you try to sign in?

Comment: this is the log from the server when i'm signin in

Comment: is that your updated code? because you still haven't permit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [devise github repo](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters). It says

`To permit simple scalar values for username and email, use this`

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
end
```